# Solve Cannibals/Missionaries using breadth-first search (BFS) in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, breadth-first-search, river-crossing-puzzle

I am working on solving the classic Missionaries(M) and Cannibals(C) problem, the start state is 3 M and 3 C on the left bank and the goal state is 3M, 3C on the right bank.  I have complete the basic function in my program and I need to implemet the search-strategy such as BFS and DFS.

Basically my code is learn from the Internet. So far I can successfuly run the program with DFS method, but I try to run with BFS it always return false.  This is my very first SWI-Prolog program, I can not find where is the problem of my code.

Here is part of my code, hope you can help me find the problem of it

```
solve2 :-
   bfs([[[3,3,left]]],[0,0,right],[[3,3,left]],Solution),
   printSolution(Solution).

bfs([[[A,B,C]]],[A,B,C],_,[]).
bfs([[[A,B,C]|Visisted]|RestPaths],[D,E,F],Visisted,Moves) :-
   findall([[I,J,K],[A,B,C]|Visited]),
     (
       move([A,B,C],[I,J,K],Description),
       safe([I,J,K]),
       not(member([I,J,K],Visited)
     ),
     NewPaths
   ),
   append(RestPaths,NewPaths,CurrentPaths),
   bfs(CurrentPaths,[D,E,F],[[I,J,K]|Visisted],MoreMoves),
   Moves = [ [[A,B,C],[I,J,K],Description] | MoreMoves ].


move([A,B,left],[A1,B,right],'One missionary cross river') :-
   A > 0, A1 is A - 1.  
   % Go this state if left M > 0. New left M is M-1
.
.
.
.
.
safe([A,B,_]) :-
   (B =< A ; A = 0),
   A1 is 3-A, B1 is 3-B,
   (B1 =< A1; A1 =0).
```

I use findall to find all possible path before go to next level.  Only the one pass the safe() will be consider as possible next state.  The state will not use if it already exist.  Since my program can run with DFS so I think there is nothing wrong with move() and safe() predicate.  My BFS predicate is changing base on my DFS code, but its not work.

Comment: `findall/3` has arity 3, but in you use just one argument in your code. You also use variables `Visisted` and `Visited`. Are they supposed to be the same? Try indenting your code to make it more readable, and add some comments. Otherwise it's hard to understand what you are trying to achieve with the `findall/3` call and the following block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a very simple way to turn a depth-first search program into a breadth-first one, provided the depth-first search is directly mapped to Prolog's search.  This technique is called [iterative deepening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search).

Simply add an additional argument to ensure that the search will only go N steps deep.
So a dfs-version:

```
dfs(State) :-
   final(State).
dfs(State1) :-
   state_transition(State1, State2),
   dfs(State2).
```

Is transformed into a bfs by adding an argument for the depth. E.g. by using [successor-arithmetics](/questions/tagged/successor-arithmetics):

```
bfs(State, _) :-
   final(State).
bfs(State1, s(X)) :-
   state_transition(State1, State2),
   bfs(State2, X).
```

A goal `bfs(State,s(s(s(0))))` will now find all derivations requiring 3 or less steps. You still can perform dfs! Simply use `bfs(State,X)`.

To find all derivations use `natural_number(X), bfs(State,X)`.

Often it is useful to use a list instead of the s(X)-number.  This list might contain all intermediary states or the particular transitions performed.

You might hesitate to use this technique, because it seems to recompute a lot of intermediary states ("repeatedly expanded states").  After all, first it searches all paths with one step, then, at most two steps, then, at most three steps... However, if your problem is a search problem, the branching factor here hidden within `state_transition/2` will mitigate that overhead. To see this, consider a branching factor of 2: We only will have an overhead of a factor of two! Often, there are easy ways to regain that factor of two: E.g., by speeding up `state_transition/2` or `final/1`.

But the biggest advantage is that it does not consume a lot of space - in contrast to naive dfs.

Comment: "[for dfs] simply use `bfs(State,X)`" this is beautiful. :)

Answer (score 1):

The Logtalk distribution includes an example, "searching", which implements a framework for state space searching:

https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/tree/master/examples/searching

The "classical" problems are included (farmer, missionaries and cannibals, puzzle 8, bridge, water jugs, etc). Some of the search algorithms are adapted (with permission) from Ivan Bratko's book "Prolog programming for artificial intelligence". The example also includes a performance monitor that can give you some basic stats on the performance of a search method (e.g. branching factors and number of state transitions). The framework is easy to extend, both for new problems and new search methods.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still interested in this for a python solution please find the following.
For the simplification, count of Missionaries and Cannibals on left is only taken to the consideration.

This is the solution tree.
 [image: solution tree]

```
#M #missionaries in left
#C #cannibals in left
# B=1left
# B=0right

def is_valid(state):
    if(state[0]>3 or state[1]>3 or state[2]>1 or state[0]<0 or state[1]<0 or state[2]<0 or (0<state[0]<state[1]) or (0<(3-state[0])<(3-state[1]))):
        return False
    else:
        return True

def generate_next_states(M,C,B):
    moves = [[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [2, 0, 1], [0, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
    valid_states = []
    for each in moves:
        if(B==1):next_state = [x1 - x2 for (x1, x2) in zip([M, C, B], each)]
        else:next_state = [x1 + x2 for (x1, x2) in zip([M, C, B], each)]
        if (is_valid(next_state)):
            # print(next_state)
            valid_states.append(next_state)
    return valid_states
solutions = []
def find_sol(M,C,B,visited):
    if([M,C,B]==[0,0,0]):#everyne crossed successfully
        # print("Solution reached, steps: ",visited+[[0,0,0]])
        solutions.append(visited+[[0,0,0]])
        return True
    elif([M,C,B] in visited):#prevent looping
        return False
    else:
        visited.append([M,C,B])
        if(B==1):#boat is in left
            for each_s in generate_next_states(M,C,B):
                find_sol(each_s[0],each_s[1],each_s[2],visited[:])
        else:#boat in in right
            for each_s in generate_next_states(M,C,B):
                find_sol(each_s[0],each_s[1],each_s[2],visited[:])


find_sol(3,3,1,[])

solutions.sort()
for each_sol in solutions:
    print(each_sol)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this gist to see a possible solution, maybe helpful to your problem.

Gist: [solve Missionaries and cannibals in Prolog](https://gist.github.com/2270011)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved with depth-first and then with breadth-first, attempting to clearly separate the reusable part from the state search algorithm:

```
miss_cann_dfs :-
    initial(I),
    solve_dfs(I, [I], Path),
    maplist(writeln, Path), nl.

solve_dfs(S, RPath, Path) :-
    final(S),
    reverse(RPath, Path).
solve_dfs(S, SoFar, Path) :-
    move(S, T),
    \+ memberchk(T, SoFar),
    solve_dfs(T, [T|SoFar], Path).

miss_cann_bfs :-
    initial(I),
    solve_bfs([[I]], Path),
    maplist(writeln, Path), nl.

solve_bfs(Paths, Path) :-
    extend(Paths, Extended),
    (   member(RPath, Extended),
        RPath = [H|_],
        final(H),
        reverse(RPath, Path)
    ;   solve_bfs(Extended, Path)
    ).

extend(Paths, Extended) :-
    findall([Q,H|R],
        (   member([H|R], Paths),
            move(H, Q),
            \+ member(Q, R)
        ), Extended),
    Extended \= [].

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% problem representation
% independent from search method
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

initial((3,3, >, 0,0)).
final((0,0, <, 3,3)).

% apply a *valid* move
move((M1i,C1i, Bi, M2i,C2i), (M1f,C1f, Bf, M2f,C2f)) :-
    direction(Bi, F1, F2, Bf),
    who_move(MM, CM),
    M1f is M1i + MM * F1, M1f >= 0,
    C1f is C1i + CM * F1, C1f >= 0,
    ( M1f >= C1f ; M1f == 0 ),
    M2f is M2i + MM * F2, M2f >= 0,
    C2f is C2i + CM * F2, C2f >= 0,
    ( M2f >= C2f ; M2f == 0 ).

direction(>, -1, +1, <).
direction(<, +1, -1, >).

% valid placements on boat
who_move(M, C) :-
    M = 2, C = 0 ;
    M = 1, C = 0 ;
    M = 1, C = 1 ;
    M = 0, C = 2 ;
    M = 0, C = 1 .
```

I suggest you to structure your code in a similar way, with a predicate similar to extend/2, that make clear when to stop the search.

Comment: A framework for state-space searching, as e.g. implemented in the Logtalk "searching" example I cite above, allows you to use any combination of state space and search method.

Comment: @Paulo Moura: that framework it's a fairly complex system, how could help Shawn Lien? I see that [breadth_first1](http://trac.logtalk.org/browser/trunk/examples/searching/breadth_first1.lgt) contains a complicated expand/expandall, mutually recursive (at first glance), and I'm unable to determine, just to say, if it implements termination. That make me think my selfmade solve_bfs, so simple, and apparently general, could be wrong. I just tested comparing with dfs...

Comment: Some of the search algorithms, including breadth first, are adapted, with permission, from the Ivan Bratko's book "Prolog Programming for Artificial Intelligence". The book explains the algorithms in detail. Note that you can easily your own version of the breadth first algorithm to the framework and test with the provided examples.

Answer (score -1):

If your Prolog system has a forward chainer you can also solve
the problem by modelling it via forward chaining rules. Here
is an example how to solve a water jug problem in Jekejeke Minlog. 
The state is represented by a predicate state/2.

You first give a rule that filters duplicates as follows. The
rule says that an incoming state/2 fact should be removed,
if it is already in the forward store:

```
% avoid duplicate state
unit &:- &- state(X,Y) && state(X,Y), !.
```

Then you give rules that state that search need not be continued 
when a final state is reached. In the present example we check
that one of the vessels contains 1 liter of water:

```
% halt for final states
unit &:- state(_,1), !.
unit &:- state(1,_), !.
```

As a next step one models the state transitions as forward chaining
rules. This is straight forward. We model emptying, filling and pouring
of vessels:

```
% emptying a vessel
state(0,X) &:- state(_,X).
state(X,0) &:- state(X,_).

% filling a vessel
state(5,X) &:- state(_,X).
state(X,7) &:- state(X,_).

% pouring water from one vessel to the other vessel
state(Z,T) &:- state(X,Y), Z is min(5,X+Y), T is max(0,X+Y-5).
state(T,Z) &:- state(X,Y), Z is min(7,X+Y), T is max(0,X+Y-7).
```

We can now use the forward chaining engine to do the job for us. It
will not do iterative deeping and it will also not do breadth first.
It will just do unit resolution by a strategy that is greedy for the
given fact and the process only completes, since the state space 
is finite. Here is the result:

```
?- post(state(0,0)), posted.
state(0, 0).
state(5, 0).
state(5, 7).
state(0, 7).
Etc..
```

The approach will tell you whether there is a solution, but not explain
the solution. One approach to make it explainable is to use a fact
state/4 instead of a fact state/2. The last two arguments are used for
a list of actions and for the length of the list.

The rule that avoids duplicates is then changed for a rule that picks 
the smallest solution. It reads as follows:

```
% choose shorter path
unit &:- &- state(X,Y,_,N) && state(X,Y,_,M), M<N, !.
unit &:- state(X,Y,_,N) && &- state(X,Y,_,M), N<M.
```

We then get:

```
?- post(state(0,0,[],0)), posted.
state(0, 0, [], 0).
state(5, 0, [fl], 1).
state(5, 7, [fr,fl], 2).
state(0, 5, [plr,fl], 2).
Etc..
```

With a little helper predicate we can force an explanation of
the actions that lead to a path:

```
?- post(state(0,0,[],0)), state(1,7,L,_), explain(L).
0-0
fill left vessel
5-0
pour left vessel into right vessel
0-5
fill left vessel
5-5
pour left vessel into right vessel
3-7
empty right vessel
3-0
pour left vessel into right vessel
0-3
fill left vessel
5-3
pour left vessel into right vessel
1-7
```

Bye

**Source Code: Water Jug State**
http://www.xlog.ch/jekejeke/forward/jugs3.p

**Source Code: Water Jug State and Path**
http://www.xlog.ch/jekejeke/forward/jugs3path.p